# Ubuntu how to fix Xorg session?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, xorg

Some time ago I accidentally gives 777 permissions to all folders, and when I reboot my system I can't login.I don't remember what exactly I do , but I can start ubuntu via wayland session. System working fine except google hangouts(unavailable screen sharing), so I find some [advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966779/why-are-some-of-my-screen-recording-capturing-applications-or-app-features-not) where need to switch to the Xorg session and then screen sharing would be available.

I tryed uncomented this line `#WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, but then after rebooting system can't run, so through recovery mode I commented again this string, and then ubuntu started on wayland session. (Also when system is booting login menu not appeared and I can't switch between sessions.)

So I supposed Xorg session is broken and I need yours suggestions how I can resolve this problem.